# добавить и вывести данные из mysql с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Делаю это в учебных целях, чтоб набить руку.

Есть таблица **cat**  с полями **id, name, catalog, price**.

Задача такая:

1. Добавить данные с помощью **input** (данные отправляются в JSON формате).
2. Вывести значения с помощью ajax.

Не обращайте внимания, что не обработал данные от инъекции и тд.

И так:

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="id" placeholder="Введите ID...">
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" placeholder="Введите наименование...">
<select id="catalog">
     <option value="Компьютеры">Компьютеры</option>
     <option value="Телефоны">Телефоны</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="price" placeholder="Введите цену...">
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Отправить">
```

Функция **show()**

```
//объкт товара
function Item() {
        this.id = "";
        this.name = "";
        this.catalog = "";
        this.price = "";
      }
function show() {
        var item = new Item();
          item.id = $("#id").val();
          item.name = $("#name").val();
          item.catalog = $("#catalog").val();
          item.price = $("#price").val();
        //cоздание JSON-объекта
        var itemJSON = JSON.stringify(item);

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (req.readyState != 4) return;
          var item = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
          //создание таблицы и вставка элементов
          ..............
        }
        req.open("POST", "test1.php", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        req.send(itemJSON);
```

и сам "сервер" **test1.php**

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "catalog");

$item = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = $item->id;
$name = $item->name;
$catalog = $item->catalog;
$price = $item->price;

$q = "INSERT INTO cat VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$catalog', '$price')";
$q2 = "SELECT id, name, catalog, price FROM cat WHERE id='$id";

if(mysqli_query($link, $q)) {

  $res = mysqli_query($link, $q2);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
}
echo json_encode($row);
```

В общем сами вопросы:
   1. Почему ответ от сервера приходит null?
   2. Можно ли использовать несколько запросов в одном файле?
   3. Правильно ли я делаю?
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: много где может быть затык. Какова структура базы данных, позволяет ли вставлять те данные что вы присылаете, что пишет консоль браузера? сделайте print_r($item), print $q, что возвращает mysqli_query? проверяйте все это

Comment: покажите SHOW CREATE TABLE вашей таблицы.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, спасибо, что ответили.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в общем, я сам подумал и сделал, теперь все работает. Даже добавил изменение данных. Все дело было в том, что ответ от сервера неправильно писал

Answer (score 1):

**id в MySql нужно указать primary key auto_increment**
Вставлять свой id в таблицу это плохая практика

**HTML**

```
<form id="addProduct">
    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Введите наименование...">
    <select  name="category">
        <option value="1">Компьютеры</option>
        <option value="2">Телефоны</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="price"  placeholder="Введите цену...">
    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить">
</form>


<div id="product-list"></div>
```

**jQUERY**

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    function _addProduct() {
        var formProduct = $('#addProduct'),
                formData = formData.serialize();

        formProduct.on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'yoUrl',
                method: 'post',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (respons) {
                    alert('Данные добавлены успешно');
                    _getProducts();
                }
            })

        });
    }

    function _getProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'yoUrl',
            method: 'post',
            data: {getProduct: true},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (respons) {

                var html = "<table>";
                    html += "<tr><th>id</th> <th>имя</th>  <th>категория</th>  <th>Цена</th></tr>";

                $.each(respons, function (key, val) {
                    html+= "<tr><td>val.id</td><td>val.name</td><td>val.category</td><td>val.price</td></tr>"
                });
                    html+= "</table>";


                $('#product-list').html(html);
            }
        })
    }

    return {
        addProduct: _addProduct(),
    }

}());
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "catalog");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $data = [

            'name' => $_POST['name'],

            'category' => $_POST['category'],

            'price' => $_POST['price']

    ];

    $query  =  $link->prepare("INSERT INTO cat ('name', 'category', 'price') VALUES ('?', '?', '?')");
    $query->bind_param($data['name'], $data['category'], $data['price']);

    return json_encode(['status'=> 'success']);

    mysqli_close($link);
}

if (isset($_POST['getProduct']) && $_POST['getProduct'] === true ) {

    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM cat";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $q)) {

        $res = mysqli_query($link, $q2);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    }
    return json_encode($row);

    mysqli_close($link);

}
```